# Disabling Journaling in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ext4, shredding

I installed Xubuntu (sometimes running Cinnamon, but I digress) and would like to disable journaling in order to make file-shredding the ext4 system partition more effective (non-system/app data is on an NTFS partition). How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Whatever you do you, make a backup before you play with filesystems!
- Check the manpages ( [man tune2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs) ) before using this!
- This only works on ext filesystems!

To disable journaling you can use (where XN points to your partition letter and digit):

```
tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdXN
```

---

From the man page:

> **tune2fs** - adjust tunable filesystem parameters on ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems
>
> **Option: -O [^]feature[,...]**
>
> Set or clear the indicated filesystem features (options) in the filesystem. More than one filesystem feature can be cleared or set by separating features with commas. **Filesystem features prefixed with a caret character ('^') will be cleared in the filesystem's superblock; filesystem features without a prefix character or prefixed with a plus character ('+') will be added to the filesystem**.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> has_journal
> ```
>
> Use a journal to ensure filesystem consistency even across unclean shutdowns. Setting the filesystem feature is equivalent to using the -j option.

You might also need the ...

> **Option: -f**
>
> Force the tune2fs operation to complete even in the face of errors. This option is useful when removing the has_journal filesystem feature from a filesystem which has an external journal (or is corrupted such that it appears to have an external journal), but that external journal is not available.
>
> WARNING: Removing an external journal from a filesystem which was not cleanly unmounted without first replaying the external journal can result in severe data loss and filesystem corruption.

---

The filesystem needs to be either unmounted or in read-only mode. From the grub prompt: "advanced options" -> "recovery mode" -> "Drop to a root shell prompt" or use a Live DVD.

Comment: 'The has_journal feature may only be cleared when the filesystem is
unmounted or mounted read-only.'

Do I have to boot the live-disk in order to perform this operation?

Comment: No, you can do it from a grub prompt too but it will be the easiests method.