# Best practice for encrypted external ssd

Tags: filesystem, encryption, ssd, luks

I want to have an encrypted external ssd for occasional backups. It seems like consumer products don't really support linux, so unless someone has a better suggestion I'm planning to format it myself and use software encryption, using LUKS with some filesystem inside.

1. Does this make sense?
2. Which filesystem should I choose?
3. Any features I should watch out for when buying the ssd?

Relevant aspects to answer these questions are mainly:

- Stability
- Lifetime of the device
- Checksums like in btrfs or zfs would be nice, but aren't a hard requirement

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> Does this make sense?

Yes, it does

> Which filesystem should I choose?

This depends on your needs. I use ext4 because I am used to it and also use it on my laptop's `/home` partition. I also do not care for non-linux interoperability (by the way if you use luks for encryption you probably do not care either).

> Any features I should watch out for when buying the ssd?

This is off topic on this site and unfortunately something I can not answer. I tend to buy cheap external disks, but I also have always two active backups.

Comment: So if you use ext4, do you disable journaling? Some people seem to consider journaling an issue for longevity https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/best-ssd-friendly-file-systems-on-linux/ Does anyone share the concerns raised on this site? Does it make a large difference for longevity which filesystem I use?

Comment: I must confess I never bothered to disable it, but probably it makes sense.Here is how it can be done: https://askubuntu.com/questions/573957/disabling-journaling-in-ubuntu-14-04